# How can I extract private and public keys from a .CER file?

Tags: openssl, public-key-encryption, private-key, public-key

I have a .CER file on my machine. I would like to print private and public keys from it and store it in DB. How can I do that?

So far, after googling around, this is what I have tried and I am hitting following error.

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in apple_pay.cer -pubkey -noout > apple_pay.pem

openssl x509 -in apple_pay.pem -text
unable to load certificate
69889:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-59.60.1/src/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:648:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
KOPC02KW5T9F6T6:ApplePaySwag-Starter chandeln$
```

I also tried following commands from https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/pkey.html

```
KOPC02KW5T9F6T6:ApplePaySwag-Starter chandeln$ openssl pkey -in apple_pay.pem -text -noout
openssl:Error: 'pkey' is an invalid command.
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After executing `openssl x509 -inform der -in apple_pay.cer -pubkey -noout > apple_pay.pem` you have public key in `apple_pay.pem`

`openssl x509` works with x509 certificates, so it unable to load public key from `apple_pay.pem`.

There are no way to extract private key from certificate or public key.
It is main idea of asymmetric cypher.